# Select Multiple Elements in XML

Tags: c#, xml, windows, linq

I have the following XML (cut down version) file:

```
<Service z:Id="i1" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<routes>
<Route z:Id="i4">
  <timetables>

      <Timetable z:Id="i8">
      <timetableId>11061</timetableId>
      </Timetable>

      <Timetable z:Id="i8">         
      <timetableId>11062</timetableId>   
      </Timetable>

   </timetables>
   </Route>
 </routes>
</Service>
```

I am able to get the first ID: 11061, but I wish to get the second one, in the real file there will be several others. But I assume once I can get two it will get more than 2.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("timetableTest.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary";

        var routeNames = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "Service").Descendants(ns + "routes").Descendants(ns + "Route")//.Descendants(ns + "timetables")//.Descendants(ns + "Service")
                          select new RootContainer
                          {
                              Services = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "timetables")//.Elements(ns + "clients")
                                                                              // where n.Elements(ns + "Service") != null
                                          select new Services

                                          {
                                              ServiceName = s.Element(ns + "Timetable").Element(ns + "timetableId").Value,
                                              //serviceIconUrl = "/Assets/Services/" + s.Element(ns + "serviceName").Value + ".png",
                                             // ServiceId = s.Element(ns + "serviceId").Value
                                          }).ToList()
                          }).Single();

        listServices.ItemsSource = routeNames.Services;
```

What do I need to alter in order to get multiple Timetable Ids?

Update: How do I do the same but with two routes? Just re-looked at the original xml feed.

```
<Service z:Id="i1" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<routes>
<Route z:Id="i4">
  <timetables>

      <Timetable z:Id="i8">
      <timetableId>11061</timetableId>
      </Timetable>

      <Timetable z:Id="i8">         
      <timetableId>11062</timetableId>   
      </Timetable>

   </timetables>
   </Route>
 <Route z:Id="i4">
  <timetables>

      <Timetable z:Id="i8">
      <timetableId>11061</timetableId>
      </Timetable>

      <Timetable z:Id="i8">         
      <timetableId>11062</timetableId>   
      </Timetable>

   </timetables>
   </Route>

 </routes>
 </Service>
```

Comment: You realize that there is a very suspicious looking `.Single()`at the end of your select.?

Also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes(v=vs.110).aspx

looks a lot easiert than this nested LINQ

Answer (score 0):

You need a compound [from clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx#Compound%20from%20Clauses) to select many timetables:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("timetableTest.xml");
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary";

    var routeNames = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "Service").Descendants(ns + "routes").Descendants(ns + "Route")//.Descendants(ns + "timetables")//.Descendants(ns + "Service")
                      select new 
                      {
                          Services = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "timetables")//.Elements(ns + "clients")
                                      from t in s.Descendants(ns + "Timetable")                              // where n.Elements(ns + "Service") != null
                                      select new 

                                      {
                                          ServiceName = t.Element(ns + "timetableId").Value,
                                          //serviceIconUrl = "/Assets/Services/" + s.Element(ns + "serviceName").Value + ".png",
                                         // ServiceId = s.Element(ns + "serviceId").Value
                                      }).ToList()
                      }).Single();

    listServices.ItemsSource = routeNames.Services;
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin, How do I now select an item in the list box in the usual way? 'var Service = (Timetables)routeNames.SelectedItem;

Answer (score 0):

Use descendants in internal for loop RootContainer class

```
Services = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "timetables").Descendants(ns +"Timetable")
```

and access directly in element

```
ServiceName = s.Element(ns + "timetableId").Value,
```

full code

```
var routeNames = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "Service").Descendants(ns + "routes").Descendants(ns + "Route")//.Descendants(ns + "timetables")//.Descendants(ns + "Service")
                          select new RootContainer
                          {
                              Services = (from s in n.Elements(ns + "timetables").Descendants(ns +"Timetable")
                                                                              // where n.Elements(ns + "Service") != null
                                          select new Services

                                          {
                                              ServiceName = s.Element(ns + "timetableId").Value,
                                              //serviceIconUrl = "/Assets/Services/" + s.Element(ns + "serviceName").Value + ".png",
                                             // ServiceId = s.Element(ns + "serviceId").Value
                                          }).ToList()
                          }).Single();
```